# Remote access to a Jetson Nano

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to remotely access a Jetson Nano from my mac. So far I have done the following:

1. I installed microsoft Remote Desktop on my mac
2. I connected the nano with my mac through the Micro-usb Port
3. In network I could see the connection "linux for Tegra" where my nano would be 192.168.55.1

With this I still cannot remote access the nano

So I open a terminal and typed

```
>ssh username@192.168.55.1
```

and I could access the nano terminal.

So I think now, I have to do

```
>sudo apt install xrdp
```

in order to be able to remotely access the GUI.

However, the nano does not have internet connection.
Is there a way that it can use the internet connection of my mac to do this?

(I am reading a tutorial on Rasppi with windows and apparently this is possible)

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches is to install [X server for mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341) and then use ssh -Y username@192.168.55.1. You will get the command line shell first but you can type in commands like `gedit` - they windows will show up on the host.

192.168.55.1 is the same network as any other. All tools supposed to work over TCP/IP should work with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

USB is a Serial connection by default.

On windows use a putty based tool.
For example start with MobaXterm > New session > Serial @11500

- Login
- Password

It won't forward internet by default.

Best simple way is to plug in your phone as USB network sharing and plug in to the laptop via micro-USB.

For Linux, Ubuntu, use a serial ("COM" related stuff) tool.

---

If you want to do ssh through USB it will require custom editing of networking file.
By default Nano is using a bridge called L4TBRO on 192.168.55.1, laptop is client in .100.
DNS server is on Nano's side.
You would have to create a new interface but using your laptop as DCHP and DNS servers.

---

Note that usb can power the Jetson Nano for continuous execution on a recent laptop. Some recommends not to and it may crash if you run a compilation on all cores. (if it crashes, just disable 2 cores via `nvpmodel -m 1`)